# How to Add Pagination to Custom JPA Query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know how to use Pagination when using default JPA-provided queries like "findAll", etc. (BASIC)
However, I created my own Custom Query in my repository:

```
public interface HeroRepository extends JpaRepository<Hero,Long>{
     @Query(value = "SELECT h.heroname , SUM(h.killCount) AS killcount FROM Heroes AS h GROUP BY h.heroname ORDER BY h.heroname",nativeQuery = true)     
     List<IHero> findAllHeroByGroupName();
}
```

Now I dont know how to add Pagination with custom queries and use custom Pageable implementation. This is what I have so far and it's not fetching anything from DB. It says "0" results when I log it. So nothing is displayed on my front-end.

**Repository:**

```
public interface HeroRepository extends JpaRepository<Hero,Long>{

@Query( value = "SELECT h.heroname , SUM(h.killCount) FROM Heroes AS h GROUP BY h.heroname ORDER BY h.heroname #{#pageable}",nativeQuery = true)     
        Page<IHero> findAllHeroByGroupName(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Service:**

```
public Page<IHero> findAllHeroByGroupName(int pageNum) {    
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNum, 10);    
    return  agentRepository.findAllHeroByGroupName(pageable);   
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    private List<IHero> heroList = new ArrayList<>();
   
    @GetMapping("/hero")
    public String goToHeroPage(Model model) {
            return viewHeroPage(model, 1);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/heropage/{pageNum}")
    public String viewHeroPage(Model model, 
            @PathVariable(name = "pageNum") int pageNum) {
        
         Page<IHero> page = heroService.findAllHeroByGroupName(pageNum);
         System.out.println("heroList SIZE "+heroList.size());
        
         model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNum);        
         model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
         model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());

         model.addAttribute("heroList", page.getContent() );
         return "heropage";
    }
```

When I check the `heroList.size()`, it says "0". When Im using the old query (top most code), everything is working fine (but I need pagination).

So How can I add pagination to my custom JPA query?

Comment: What is the relational between `page` and `heroList` in your controller?

Comment: @samabcde I updated the controller code so you have a full picture

Comment: Thx for the update, but I don't see you add any element to `heroList`. What you need should be `List<Hero> heros = page.getContent()`.

Comment: @samabcde you can post that as answer,. Also do you know why adding "#{#pageable}" to the native query makes it work for MySQL?

Comment: I don't feel that will be useful for future reader. For your next question, please raise another question instead, as comment box is not suitable for question and answer.